# Create XML attribute in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following code to write some data in an xml file. It works well but the attributes. I can not create attributes and its value for an element.

```
//.xml file===========================
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Errors>
   <Error Name="abc" ContactNo="123">
     <Description>Test</Description>
  </Error>
</Errors>

// c# code ===========================
XmlDocument xmlErrors = new XmlDocument();
xmlErrors.Load(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Errors.xml"));
XmlElement subRoot = xmlErrors.CreateElement("Error");
// subRoot.Attributes[0].Value = "Test 1";
// subRoot.Attributes[1].Value = "Test 2";
XmlElement Description = xmlErrors.CreateElement("Description");
Description.InnerText = currentData.ExamineeName;
subRoot.AppendChild(Description);
xmlErrors.DocumentElement.AppendChild(subRoot);
xmlErrors.Save(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Errors.xml"));
```

Would you please help me how to create an attribute and its value?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
XmlElement error = Errors.CreateElement("Error");
XmlAttribute errName= Errors.CreateAttribute("Name");
errName.value="abc"
error.Attributes.Append(errName);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [SetAttributeValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue?view=netframework-4.8) on a `XElement` object:

```
subRoot.SetAttributeValue("Name","Test 1");
subRoot.SetAttributeValue("ContactNo","Test 1");
```

Comment: There is no method SetAttributeValue, but SetAttribute. Anyway, thank you for giving the clue. You deserve upvote.

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ2XML

```
XElement doc=new XElement("Errors",
      new XElement("Error",new XAttribute("Name","abc"),new XAttribute("ContactNo","123")),
      new XElement("Description","Test")
);
doc.Save(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is to use the following code:

```
error.SetAttribute("id", "value");
```